# Can't find bluetooth device on nRFconnect/esp32

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

My ultimate goal is to use a BT button as a remote control to my esp32(M5StickC).
In order to do so I need to connect and get the device's data.
The device i'm trying to get data from is called "FiiO RM1"(https://headfonics.com/the-rm1-by-fiio/).
When connecting it to my smartphone there are no issues what so ever and works fine.
Once scanning through nRFconnect app or in my esp32(added code) I can't see the device's name looking at the scan results. Is there any security issue or something that's hiding it from publishing?
This is the code:

```
//This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)
//By Victor Tchistiak - 2019
//
//This example demostrates master mode bluetooth connection and pin 
//it creates a bridge between Serial and Classical Bluetooth (SPP)
//this is an extention of the SerialToSerialBT example by Evandro Copercini - 2018
//

#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

String MACadd = "0C:FC:83:99:54:12";
uint8_t address[6]  = {0x0C, 0xFC, 0x83, 0x99, 0x54, 0x12};
String name = "FiiO RM1";
char *pin = "1234"; //<- standard pin would be provided by default
bool connected;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //SerialBT.setPin(pin);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test", true); 
  //SerialBT.setPin(pin);
  Serial.println("The device started in master mode, make sure remote BT device is on!");
  
  // connect(address) is fast (upto 10 secs max), connect(name) is slow (upto 30 secs max) as it needs
  // to resolve name to address first, but it allows to connect to different devices with the same name.
  // Set CoreDebugLevel to Info to view devices bluetooth address and device names
  connected = SerialBT.connect(name);
  //connected = SerialBT.connect(address);
  
  if(connected) {
    Serial.println("Connected Succesfully!");
  } else {
    while(!SerialBT.connected(10000)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to connect. Make sure remote device is available and in range, then restart app."); 
    }
  }
  // disconnect() may take upto 10 secs max
  if (SerialBT.disconnect()) {
    Serial.println("Disconnected Succesfully!");
  }
  // this would reconnect to the name(will use address, if resolved) or address used with connect(name/address).
  SerialBT.connect();
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: There's way too much code there. Please cut it down to a minimal, viable example - something that builds that has only the code that's necessary to demonstrate the issue. You should be able to remove almost all the code that's there in order to show the problem. You'll be much more likely to get help if you do that.

Comment: @Omri are you sure the 'BT button' uses Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) and not Bluetooth classic? You tagged your question with both technologies even though they work differently. Your ESP code searches for BLE advertisements but the link you provided for the "FiiO RM1" says "Supported Bluetooth devices: BT3.0 and above". BLE was first introduced with Bluetooth version 4.0

Comment: Ok, probably is right it is BT classic(I used another app to check and can see it there), now using the code(in the edited the post) I get a connected message and nothing happens when pressing the buttons. What is the correct way to get the message?
Also added the screen shot of the device details in the app.

Comment: Could you provide us with the log output of your ESP code?

Comment: Log:
The device started in master mode, make sure remote BT device is on!
Connected Succesfully!
It says connected succesfully no matter what happens(even device turned off)
I tried connecting through name and through address